# Direct Link to Specific Calendar Event in OWA

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app

Is there a way to retrieve or reverse engineer a direct link to open a specific calendar event in Outlook Web App?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you find out a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In case you can access the calendar API and you know the event ID:

You can use this API [Get Event API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#GetEvent) to get the event info which contains "WebLink"

That WebLink works as expected for me until I turned on the "Try the Beta" switch.